# Is a composition of PRGs itself a PRG?

Tags: cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-function

I have this question:

> Given $G_1$, $G_2$ are PRG's. Is $H(s)=G_1(G_2(s))$ also a PRG?

Thank you.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried and failed? Where are you stuck? Also, is this homework?

Comment: I have a proof of a friend, he used hybrid proof and probabilities. And this is not homework, we are studying for a test.

Comment: My point is that you have to give more detail in your question. Share your research so we can accurately answer. Otherwise, at best, you'll get answers restating what you already know, or even get people thinking you put no effort into this and not answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

Without answering the question, here is a hint:

Assume $H(s) = G_1(G_2(s))$ is *not* a PRG. That is, there exists an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ that distinguishes $H(s)$ from a uniform string. Can we use this adversary to contradict the pseudorandomness of $G_1$ or $G_2$?

Comment: That's not a hint, it's how almost every proof in the area goes.

Comment: Obviously, but I thought it might help the OP to give some plain-English intuition about how the proof goes.